# Preferred block size when reading/writing big binary files

Tags: python, file, python-3.4

I need to read and write huge binary files. Is there a preferred or even optimal number of bytes (what I call `BLOCK_SIZE`) I should `read()` at a time?

One byte is certainly too little, and I do not think reading 4 GB into the RAM is a good idea either - is there a 'best' block size? or does that even depend on the file-system (I'm on [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4))? What do I need to consider?

[Python's `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) even provides a `buffering` argument. Would I need to tweak that as well?

This is sample code that just joins the two files `in-0.data` and `in-1.data` into `out.data` (in real life there is more processing that is irrelevant to the question at hand). The `BLOCK_SIZE` is chosen equal to [`io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) which seems to be the default for `buffering`:

```
from pathlib import Path
from functools import partial

DATA_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / '../data/'

out_path = DATA_PATH / 'out.data'
in_paths = (DATA_PATH / 'in-0.data', DATA_PATH / 'in-1.data')

BLOCK_SIZE = 8192

def process(data):
    pass

with out_path.open('wb') as out_file:
    for in_path in in_paths:
        with in_path.open('rb') as in_file:
            for data in iter(partial(in_file.read, BLOCK_SIZE), b''):
                process(data)
                out_file.write(data)
#            while True:
#                data = in_file.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
#                if not data:
#                    break
#                process(data)
#                out_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Not sure there is a definitive answer for this, likely dependent on OS, file-system and physical disk on the machine in question.  If this is intended to be a generic solution, you may want to add code to interrogate the system for parameters to calculate the best answer.

Comment: i was hoping to have 'interrogated the system' by using `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` - but i really have no experience with the details of all  this...

Comment: There's no single static answer for this even on a given system. It depends on a large number of variables, some of which can change over time or be different each time. as well as what else your program or the system is doing. The best approach might be to write something to determine a good size at that moment using certain unchanging representative test file(s). Alternatively you could write a standalone test and run it once to get a good estimate and then hardcode into your application (or make the test part of the installation or set-up process).

Comment: how would i 'determine a good size'? benchmark and check what is most efficient? the processing i need to do does not care much about  the size of `data`.

Comment: You need to benchmark, this blog post is related http://rabexc.org/posts/io-performance-in-python. What are you doing with the data? If you are writing then the buffer size is also relevant as that can affect the performance

Comment: interesting, thanks! did not know about `io.open()` and `readinto()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let the OS make the decision for you. Use the mmap module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

It uses your OS's underlying memory mapping mechanism for mapping the contents of a file into RAM.

Be aware that there's a 2GB file size limit if you're using 32-bit Python, so be sure to use the 64-bit version if you decide to go this route.

For example:

```
f1 = open('input_file', 'r+b')
m1 = mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(), 0)
f2 = open('out_file', 'a+b') # out_file must be >0 bytes on windows
m2 = mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0)
m2.resize(len(m1))
m2[:] = m1 # copy input_file to out_file
m2.flush() # flush results
```

Note that you never had to call any read() functions and decide how many bytes to bring into RAM. This example just copies one file into another, but as you said in your example, you can do whatever processing you need in between. Note that while the entire file is mapped to an address space in RAM, that doesn't mean it has actually been copied there. It will be copied piecewise, at the discretion of the OS.

Comment: if i understand correctly i'd still need to decide on the number of bytes `n` i'd want to [`read([n])`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap.read). then i'm back to my original problem. or what am i missing?

Comment: I'm trying some code now, but essentially mmap gives you a bytearray interface to your data, in addition to the file interface. So you can access, process, etc your data as if it were in a bytearray already.

Comment: how do i profit from a `bytearray`? my `data` is of the type `<class 'bytes'>` already - which is perfectly fine for what i need. but i'm interested to see where this is going!

Comment: I've added example code and a bit more explanation.

Comment: ok. that looks nice! assuming i have a function `process(data)` that needs to access all the bytes in the file sequentially (but the size of `data` does not matter) - i'd think this approach would go  twice through the data of a file. or how would i call `process(data)` in a smart & efficient way?

Comment: That's part of the beauty of mmap. The data won't actually be read from the disk until it's actually used. "m2 = mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0)" doesn't read any data from disk into RAM. Nor does "len(m1)". Only at "m2[:] = m1" does data get read from input_file on disk. So, for your case, you'd call "process(m2)" assuming code in process treats m2 as a sequence. If process() moves sequentially through the indices of the m2 "bytearray", the data will only be read once from disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90476/discussion-between-chad-kennedy-and-hiro-protagonist).