# Writing data to disk in a disk-friendly way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I was wondering if there's anything I can do within my python code, that makes `i/o` more disk friendly?

I know that, by default, `open()` uses a heuristically determined buffer with the size of the disk's `blocksize`.

From what I understand, this only determines when data is flushed to the disk's cache. Is this correct?

I have the following scenario:

I'm hooking into various websockets which constantly stream data. I need this data written to disk. Optimally, I'd have as little lag between receiving and `i/o` action as possible, while not murdering my disks with `i/o` commands.

I'm already using a single thread to write all data, as opposed to dropping data from various threads ([as has been pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254147/writing-data-to-disk-in-parallel)). But I was wondering if it makes sense to set the buffer to anything else but the `default` here?

I realize the load will be daunting anyway, but I was curious if there's any best practices to be disk-friendly, when writing python code for this kind of scenario.

Currently, I'm just doing this:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write("stuff")
```

Comment: Caching/buffering both by the hard disk and by the Operating System is your cheapest optimization, I'd say - are you sure you've optimized both before bending your own code?

Comment: "Optimally, I'd have as little lag between receiving and i/o action as possible" sounds really soft. Why do you need fast i/o action?

Comment: may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748231/preferred-block-size-when-reading-writing-big-binary-files

Comment: @tiwo, because I want to ensure that in case my machine catches fire (metaphorically speaking), I'll lose as little data as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I was wondering if it makes sense to set the buffer to anything else but the default here?

It might - but any performance improvement you see would depend strongly on the system you're running on - the OS, the file system, the hardware, and even the way data is laid out on disk.  So your performance might even be strongly dependent on the past history of file system usage as files get created, written, modified, and deleted.  Change the storage from a single local 5400-rpm SATA drive to a NAS system with a RAID-6 array of 15K-rpm SAS drives?  Your answer will likely be different.

The only real way to know is to test it - on the system you plan on using it on.  Or at least one as identical as you can make it.  And you need to test using the same pattern of I/O operations your process would actually perform.  It makes no sense to perform a bunch of large sequential writes if your I/O pattern is small reads from random locations.

And in the end, unless you're running on a system actually designed to handle your specific I/O pattern, you'll probably conclude it wasn't worth the effort to do all the testing.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you end up going with I would recommend trying each method with "IPython %timeit" and compare what works best for your data and your hardware.

Here is a simple example of a chunked writer.  ASCII characters (one at a time) are loaded into writeBuff.  When the write buffer hits 1024 characters, the block is written to disk.

```
import string
import random
import time

totalLength = 2**20
charsWritten = 0
writeBuff = ""

f = open("myFile.txt", "w")
while charsWritten < totalLength:
    writeBuff += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    charsWritten += 1
    if len(writeBuff) == 1024:
        f.write(writeBuff)
        writeBuff = ""    
f.write(writeBuff)
f.close()
```