# Efficiently reading binary files in Python

Tags: python, file, binary, iteration

I'm fairly new to Python;  I have a script that reads thru a binary file a byte at a time and I'm looking to improve the execution time.  I'm assuming that this is very inefficient from an I/O perspective:

```
With InputFile:    
    InByte = InputFile.read(1)
    while InByte != b'':
        # Do stuff
        InByte = InputFile.read(1)
```

I'm thinking that reading a much larger chunk of data (e.g. read(1000000000)) and then iterating thru that would be more efficient.  With my C head on this would be a large heap area and a char pointer and, when the buffer is exhausted, resetting the pointer and loading another chunk into the buffer.  Iterating thru the string is an option but at certain points I would want to deal with multiple bytes and then jump my pointer ahead by that amount, and I don't think that's possible with a string iterator.

Are there efficient ways to do this kind of processing in Python or, since speed is important, would I be better off just using C?  For context, I'm trying to determine the encoding of a file - similar to the Linux "file" command but gathering more detailed metrics.

**EDIT:**
Having implemented a buffered read thus (code simplified):

```
With InputFile:    
    InString = InputFile.read(BufferSize)
    
    while ChunksToProcess:
        for InByte in InString:
            # Do stuff
         
        InString = InputFile.read(BufferSize)
```

I ran a large file thru with a 1 byte buffer and got a processing rate of 305,836 B/s.  Running with a 10,000 byte buffer I got 346,950 B/s.  Any buffer size above 10,000 got the same throughput.  10,000 also seemed to be the largest size that showed any improvement.

I'm surprised by this as I thought the processing would be I/O bound but it seems to be processor bound.  I think my options now are to see if I can multi-thread the "Do stuff" processing (which would be difficult as this could split a related group of bytes) or resort to a compiled language such as C.

Comment: may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748231/preferred-block-size-when-reading-writing-big-binary-files

Comment: Your chunk size should be reasonably large. What exactly is reasonable depends on many factory like your memory, the CPU workload and the media you read from. There is no one size fits all perfectly value.